# How to implement the extraction operator in a class?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading, stream-operators

I have a class that reads parts of a binary file into variables of different types.

```
class Foo {
public:
    size_t getSizeT();
    float getFloat();
    std::string getString();
private:
    std::ifstream stream;
};
```

Now I'd like to implement the stream extraction operator as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/1079110).

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo &operator>>(Foo &foo, size_t &value);
    Foo &operator>>(Foo &foo, float &value);
    Foo &operator>>(Foo &foo, std::string &value);
private:
    std::ifstream stream;
};
```

The code fails to compile with this error message: `error C2804: binary 'operator >>' has too many parameters`. How to properly override the stream extraction operator? It should distinguish between types and be chainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As free function, operator signature should be:

```
Foo& operator >>(Foo& foo, size_t& value);
```

As member function (your case), it should be:

```
Foo& operator >>(size_t& value);
```

Answer (score 2):

If an instance of your class is the source of the data, then you have two ways of writing the input operator function: Either as a stand-alone global function taking two arguments, the instance of your class and the destination object. Or you write it as a member-function of your class, and then it takes only a single argument which is the destination.

So for a global function you write e.g.

```
class Foo { ... };

Foo& operator>>(Foo& foo, int& i)
{
    // Get an integer and writes to `i` here
    return foo;
}
```

For a member function you write e.g.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ...

    Foo& operator>>(int& i)
    {
        // Get an integer and writes to `i` here
        return *this;
    }
};
```

---

The reason I think you wrote the operator wrong, is because you can write the first version, using global functions, as *friend* function inline inside a class, and you have seen that before mistaking between the difference between a friend function and a member function.

You use friend functions like

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ...

    // Notice the keyword `friend` 
    friend Foo& operator>>(Foo& foo, int& i)
    {
        // Get an integer and writes to `i` here
        return foo;
    }
};
```

The difference between a member function and a friend function is subtle but very important.